# AngularJS File Upload throwing 403 Forbidden - IIS Windows Server

Tags: angularjs, iis, windows-server-2008

In my application, I am using AngularJS file upload to read excel file uploaded. In my controller I am having the upload method like below,

```
Upload.upload({
         url: 'upload/url',
         file: file
   }).progress(function (evt) {
      console.log("Progress");
   }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
      console.log("Success");
   });
 });
```

But this Upload.upload is failing with below message

```
Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":"<html>\r\n<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>\r\n<body>\r\n<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->\r\n<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->\r\n<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->\r\n<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->\r\n<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->\r\n<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->\r\n","status":403,"config":{"method":"POST","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"upload/url","file":{},"_isDigested":true,"_chunkSize":null,"headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*","Authorization":"Bearer <token>"},"_deferred":{"promise":{}},"cached":false},"statusText":"","xhrStatus":"complete"}
```

I tried validating the full access to IIS_Users for the folder where source code is available.

Help me with fixing the issue.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis 403.x has little to do with "full access to IIS_USRS". Use FRT to learn more on what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the firewall, which blocks the file upload. Post removing it able to upload files.